# Reduce Stages in Jenkinsfile when using Multibranch Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

In this Jenkinsfile I am trying to execute the same stage for different branches in Multibranch Pipeline. I need to configure the environment variable of each branch-name every time. Is there any better way to do this?

```
        stage('Create New AMI for master branch') {
            when { branch 'master' }
            environment {
                BRANCH_NAME = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                ENV_NAME = "prod"
            }
            steps {
                sh "packer build jenkins/${PROJECT_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}-ami.json"
            }
        }
        stage('Create New AMI for development branch') {
            when { branch 'development' }
            environment {
                BRANCH_NAME = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                ENV_NAME = "dev"
            }
            steps {
                sh "packer build jenkins/${PROJECT_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}-ami.json"
            }
        }
        stage('Create New AMI for staging branch') {
            when { branch 'staging' }
            environment {
                BRANCH_NAME = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                ENV_NAME = "staging"
            }
            steps {
                sh "packer build jenkins/${PROJECT_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}-ami.json"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use shared library in this case which will contain all your stage implementations.Reference Example implemenation as shown below.

Create a file named : sharedlibraries (groovy file)

```
#!groovy
// Write or add Functions(definations of stages) which will be called from your jenkins file
def Create_AMI(PROJECT_NAME, ENV_NAME)
 {
     echo ENV_NAME
     sh "packer build jenkins/${PROJECT_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}-ami.json"
     // You can also set the environment below example:
     env.ENV_NAME ="dev"
 }

return this
```

In your Jenkinsfile write below code:

```
// Global variable is used to get data from groovy file(shared library)
def stagelibrary
stage('Create New AMI') {   
            steps {
              script {
                        // Load Shared library Groovy file stagelibraries.Give your path of stagelibraries file whic is created
                        stagelibrary = load 'C:\\Jenkins\\stagelibraries'
                        // Execute Create_AMI function. You can add if else conditions over here, based on your branches. But am not sure of your conditions.
                        // You can also pass your environment variable 
                        // in the Crete_AMI function using env.<YOURENVVARIABLE>
                        stagelibrary.Create_AMI(PROJECT_NAME,env.ENV_NAME)       
                      }               
                  }
        }
```

The above example was shown to provide overview of shared library and you dont need to write same functions / or redundant stages.

Comment: Hey @Altaf thanks for giving new perspective but I want the ENV_NAME as well so how can I use it? Also does this will pass all global Env vars to packer step?

Comment: @Hiren, yes you can use the environment variables in the same way even in the packer step. Example: jobName= env.JOB_NAME

Comment: @Hiren does the solution I provided works for you

Comment: Hi @altaf I am still not clear on How can I use ENV_NAME = "dev" / "Stage" / "prod" using shared library in your example.

Comment: @Hiren I updated the answer with how to use and set environment variables by  using `env.<YOURENVVARIABLE>` eg: `env.ENV_NAME `.Either set it or use it